# Actionpack page caching rendered views on every request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, static, rubygems

I try to use **Actionpack page caching** with my static page. 
If I understand the work 'Actionpack page caching' is the first request gets to the rails. Rendered the views, and Html stored in the cache public/deploy/...

A second similar request does not reach the rails. Views will not renderd. A page will be taken from the cache.

But in the log it looks completely different.

"First Request"

```
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.591000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered init/scene.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.615000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_server_params.html.erb (4.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.624000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_login_without_social_window.html.erb (2.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.661000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_choice_base_career_window.html.erb (34.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.687000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_auth_window.html.erb (21.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.691000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_free_teams_window.erb (2.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.692000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_windows.html.erb (74.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.775000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_bottom_menu.html.erb (80.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.780000 #16835]  INFO -- : Write page /home/pri/test/public/deploy/init/load_app.html (1.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:43.782000 #16835]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 208ms (Views: 200.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.070000 #16835]  INFO -- : Started GET "/init/load_app" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-08-16 12:24:49 +0400
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.088000 #16835]  INFO -- : Processing by InitController#load_app as HTML
```

"Second Request"

```
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.096000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered init/scene.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.108000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_server_params.html.erb (2.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.112000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_login_without_social_window.html.erb (1.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.124000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_choice_base_career_window.html.erb (10.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.138000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_auth_window.html.erb (11.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.140000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered windows/_free_teams_window.erb (1.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.142000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_windows.html.erb (31.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.161000 #16835]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_bottom_menu.html.erb (16.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.165000 #16835]  INFO -- : Write page /home/pri/test/public/deploy/init/load_app.html (3.0ms)
    I, [2013-08-16T12:24:49.167000 #16835]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 76ms (Views: 70.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

In all requests views will rendered and cache page overwrited.

**I use**: 
  rails 4.0.0

jruby

puma server

production mode

start server - RAILS_ENV=production rails s puma

**my production.rb**

```
    ResFm::Application.configure do

      config.cache_classes = true
      config.eager_load = true
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
      config.cache_store = :dalli_store

      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

      config.assets.compile = false
      config.assets.digest = true
      config.assets.version = '1.0'
      config.assets.debug = false

      config.log_level = :info
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true
      config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
      config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

      # cache static pages
      config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/deploy"
      config.serve_static_assets = true

      #CDN google servers
      config.asset_host = 'http://resassets.appspot.com'
    end
```

In Controller i use

```
caches_page :load_app
def load_app

end
```

and this is a root url.

my Gemfile

```
    gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
    gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter', '~>1.3.0.beta2'
    gem 'dalli'
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
    gem 'jquery-rails'

    group :assets do
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
      gem 'therubyrhino'
      gem 'execjs'
    end

    group :development do
        gem 'annotate'
        gem 'puma'
    end

    gem 'dimensions-rails'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

    group :production do
      gem 'rack-cache'
      gem 'actionpack-page_caching'
    end
```

Please help me understand what i do wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using page caching you should instruct your webserver to serve the cached pages that get written in the public directory. The idea is that if the normal path for your request is /foo/bar.html the cached copy should be stored in Rails.root/public/foo/bar.html. That way the request never hits your Rails application.

When changing the storage path to public/deploy as you have done, you should take care to point your webserver to that directory to serve files from there. I don't think Puma handles that, so you should handle that in the frontend server (like Apache or Nginx).

Having said that, page caching was removed from Rails 4 for good reason, prehaps you should look into [Russian Doll Caching](http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/russian-doll-caching-cache-digests-rails-4-countdown-to-2013) as it's much more flexible and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks! I chacnge 

config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public/"

and caching works!